# Resolve Maven warning "The following dependencies could not be resolved at this point of the build but seem to be part of the reactor"

Tags: maven, sonarqube, multi-module

I am facing a problem with Maven multi-module project. To compile the code I am using below command:

`mvn clean package -pl <module-name> -am`

The compilation and packaging works fine, as Maven is able to detect dependent modules. However, after that I have a stage for SonarQube, and there it gives warning for all other modules, which it is not able to find (rightly so, because those modules were not built as part of this build).
`[WARNING] The following dependencies could not be resolved at this point of the build but seem to be part of the reactor:`

Is there a maven configuration through which I can get rid of these warnings ?

Answer (score 0):

See [SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/#header-6):

> #### Excluding a module from analysis
>
> • ...
>
> • use build profiles to exclude some module (like for integration tests)
>
> • use Advanced Reactor Options (such as "`-pl`"). For example `mvn sonar:sonar -pl !module2`